# How to force division into equal parts using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a dom structure like this:

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="4">
    <div id="5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with css specified as:

```
#1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#2, #4{
  flex: 1;
}
```

The divs with id 2 and 4 will be evenly distributed as long as the sum of the width of the contents in id 3 and 5 does not exceed the width of the dom with id 1.

When the sum exceeds the width, they are not evenly distributed, and one with wider content will take up more width. How can I force 2 and 4 to take up even width using flexbox even in such cases?

I do not want to use width specification by percent. I want to stick to flexbox.

Comment: First of all, `id` that starts with a number is invalid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want elements to grow or shrink independently to it's content, specify zero [flex basis](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#flex-basis):

```
flex-basis: 0;
```

However, [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxcq4/5/) incorrectly works in Chrome: large image stretches it's parent container no matter that zero basis has been set. As a workaround, maximum width can be set:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To force the equal distribution, you have to add `width: 0` to all flex items. This came to my mind after reading Manuel Matuzovic's article, which has a very good in-depth conclusion how `flex-grow` works.

https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/

Comment: Not sure why other answers out there don't say this explicitly, but this was the answer on top of everything else that fixed my problem at the end of the day