# Flexbox not giving equal width to elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Attempting a flexbox nav that has up to 5 items and as little as 3, but it's not dividing the width equally between all the elements.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY9N/1/)

The tutorial I'm modeling this after is http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fluid-width-variable-item-navigation-css/

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tabs {
  max-width: 1010px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  margin: 0 0 0 6.5rem;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tabs ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.313rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: inherit;
  left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs ul li.active {
  background: white;
  color: blue;
}
.tabs ul li:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active" data-tab="1">Pizza</li>
    <li data-tab="2">Chicken Noodle Soup</li>
    <li data-tab="3">Peanut Butter</li>
    <li data-tab="4">Fish</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: give a min-width to your table like and set padding with vw units might help : http://jsfiddle.net/2nY9N/2/ drop the flex-grow and just do flex:1; it will use defaut values for the 2 other properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force division into equal parts using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000115/how-to-force-division-into-equal-parts-using-flexbox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276).

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

There is an important bit that is not mentioned in the article to which you linked and that is `flex-basis`.  By default `flex-basis` is `auto`.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-property):

> If the specified flex-basis is auto, the used flex basis is the value of the flex item’s main size property. (This can itself be the keyword auto, which sizes the flex item based on its contents.)

Each flex item has a `flex-basis` which is sort of like its initial size.  Then from there, any remaining free space is distributed proportionally (based on `flex-grow`) among the items.  With `auto`, that basis is the contents size (or defined size with `width`, etc.).  As a result, items with bigger text within are being given more space overall in your example.

If you want your elements to be completely even, you can set `flex-basis: 0`.  This will set the flex basis to 0 and then any remaining space (which will be all space since all basises are 0) will be proportionally distributed based on `flex-grow`.

```
li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    /* ... */
}
```

[This diagram from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg) does a pretty good job of illustrating the point.

And [here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY9N/3/) with your fiddle.

Comment: This ruins wrapping for me on Safari.

Comment: The awesome thing about this answer is that you explain flex-basis with this example better than anywhere else on literally the entire internet. I'm going to contact MIT about giving you an honorary professorship.

Comment: Just to mention that `flex: 1;` is shorthand for combination of `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-basis: 0`.

Comment: Just in case if anyone wants to know in depth, I came across this great article on the web: https://css-tricks.com/flex-grow-is-weird/

Comment: Oh man, always hits me on the head when I thought I grasped CSS.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, check if one item has different horizontal padding than another, then this solution doesn't make them the same width.

Comment: you will also probably need to reset min width to zero (`min-width: 0`), because for flex it is `auto` by default and it won't allow properly sizing in some cases.

Comment: If the li items had <a></a> tags with content inside, will this still work? https://jsbin.com/huvimepomi/edit?html,css,output
Struggling to get the boxes to have same width here. Thanks.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov when `flex` has only one unitless value it's a shorthand  for `flex-grow` solely, without `flex-basis`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: `min-width: 0` was absolutely key to make it work for me

Answer (score 44):

As explained in @James Montagne answer `flex-basis: 0` will ensure the flexbox columns are distributed evenly which works in this case since the column content can wrap and isn't forcing the width. However, in cases where the width of the column content is forced (for example with image width or white-space: nowrap), the solution is to set `min-width: 0`...

```
li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/sLZxZRFduI

Comment: min-width: 0; made my items same width to achieve overflow

Comment: Excellent answer to deal with multiple flex columns containing images and text. `min-width:0;` helped to solve equal column widths

Comment: I dont need flex-bias 0 with min-width set.

Comment: I just went with the `flex-basis: 0` and that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

To create elements with equal width using `Flex`, you should set to your's child (flex elements):

```
flex-basis: 25%;
flex-grow: 0;
```

It will give to all elements in row 25% width. They will not grow and go one by one.

Comment: This is pretty awkward since it diminishes the benefit of flex entirely. If youre going to hardcode your column sizes theres easier ways to solve things.

Comment: that's not wrong at all .. if you wanna have boxes with same length and breaken down when row is fully occupied .. you can easily achieve that like this. Maybe set also min-width if you need a min width

Comment: @Kloar You're saying that like it's the only benefit of flexboxes... They can certainly still be beneficial when you need equal widths, e.g. for responsiveness. Also, it's not like flexboxes aren't easy?

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:**

```
flex: 1;
```

OR

```
.flex-child-items{
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you only put `display: flex` it just horizontally align all the item and the width is going to be `sum` of child's width (depend on the content or sometimes `width` property).

For example:

*// A normal flex*

```
++++++++++   ++++++++++   ++++++++++
+        +   +        +   +        +
+   A    +   +   B    +   +   C    +
+  10px  +   +  10px  +   +  10px  +
+        +   +        +   +        +
++++++++++   ++++++++++   ++++++++++
```

Now suppose you want to divide space equally to all of them.
To do this add `flex-grow: 1` to all children of flex. (In this example A,B and C)

```
.A, .B, .C {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

After this it looks like this:

```
++++++++++                              ++++++++++                              ++++++++++
+        +                              +        +                              +        +
+   A    +                              +   B    +                              +   C    +
+  10px  +                              +  10px  +                              +  10px  +
+        +                              +        +                              +        +
++++++++++                              ++++++++++                              ++++++++++
```

**BTW, if the above example box does not look like center, sorry for that but code work try it on the project.*

Comment: Upvoted for `flex: 1`. I like your commitment to visualize but see if you can change it to a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) instead =)

Answer (score 4):

To understand why setting the flex-grow property doesn't distribute items equally in a flex container, we need to delve into the inner workings of the flex algorithm and understand how `flex-grow` operates.

1. **Default Behavior of display:flex:**

When you set a container to `display:flex`, it defaults to `flex-direction:row`, and its flex items will have widths based on their content. In this scenario, the larger the content of an item, the wider it becomes. The `padding` and `flex-grow` have been removed from your code to show this behavior:

After removing those declarations from `.tabs ul li:{...}`:

```
flex-grow: 1;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
```

[image: Code after removing padding and flex-grow properties]

```css
* {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.tabs {
  max-width: 1010px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
  margin: 0 0 0 6.5rem;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tabs ul li {
/*   flex-grow: 1; */
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.313rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: inherit;
  left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
/*   padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px; */
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs ul li.active {
  background: white;
  color: blue;
}
.tabs ul li:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active" data-tab="1">Pizza</li>
    <li data-tab="2">Chicken Noodle Soup</li>
    <li data-tab="3">Peanut Butter</li>
    <li data-tab="4">Fish</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**2. The Role of flex-grow:**
Applying flex-grow to a flex item instructs the item to expand when there's available space within the container.

**3. Equal Distribution with `flex-grow:1`:**
If we set all items to `flex-grow:1`, like in your example, they will proportionally share the remaining space equally. However, it's essential to note that initially, they are not of equal width. The additional space is added to the initial width of each item (the content width).

Here's how it looks when we return back `flex-grow:1`:

Note that the right space after each flex item is equal but the width of items are not equal due to different content sizes
[image: After adding flex-grow:1; again]

**4. Solving the Unequal Width Issue:**
To achieve truly equal distribution, you can set the `width` of the items to 0 this will make the space available to be utilized by flex-grow and here how it looks:
[image]

Note that the blue rectangle is the border of all the items

Now we have all available space to be distributed by `flex-grow` and we can divide them evenly among flex items.

Alternatively, you can use the flex-basis property to ensure equal distribution. Setting flex-basis:0 produces a similar result. Another option is to use the shorthand property flex, where `flex:1` is equivalent to `flex-grow:1`, `flex-shrink:1`, and `flex-basis:0`.

and both options achieve the same result:

[image: width:0 or flex:1]

and here is the result after we add back the `padding`:
[image: after adding the padding again]

It's worth mentioning that the flex algorithm has a way of determining the initial width (in the case of `flex-direction:row`) and height (in the case of `flex-direction:column`) using `flex-basis` that can override the width or height property if it exists. To avoid potential bugs, it is recommended to use it or the shorthand flex property to ensure consistent and predictable behavior.

In summary, to ensure equal distribution of space among flex items, you can use `flex-basis:0` or `flex:1` with default values, while keeping in mind the nuances of the flex algorithm. This approach ensures that items in a flex container are divided equally and consistently, regardless of their initial content-based widths.

Answer (score -3):

Flex may not give equal widths to children in all cases.

> use css grid for equal width elements.

```
.el{
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-flow: column;
 grid-auto-columns: 1fr
}
```

Reference https://css-tricks.com/equal-columns-with-flexbox-its-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

If you wish to use CSS flex only, then there are few options

1. `flex-basis: 100%` to all the childs, this will be a close match.
   OR
2. `flex-basis: 0` this is less useful than first option