# Flex-grow doesn't respect border-box. Bug or not? And any way to overcome?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a CSS class that's supposed to take the remaining space of a flex-container, regardless of the amount of flex-items. Meaning that a fixed percentage `width` or `flex-basis` is not an option.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066214/flexbox-not-giving-equal-width-to-elements), applying `.flex-item { flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; }` should do the trick, but [as you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/a097q5fy/3/), it is not working when some items have a padding or borders, *even after setting box-sizing to border-box*.

Is this a bug or desired behavior? Is it possible to specify equal width for any number of flex items, regardless of padding and borders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is the desired behavior.

When you have a bunch of flex-children, and apply `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-grow: 1` to them, the following steps are being taken by the browser:

- Render text and other content the flex-children have
- Apply padding, borders and margins (taking the box-sizing into account)
- Starting with the smallest flex-child (because of `flex-basis: 0`) keep adding width to the items until the container is full (`flex-grow: 1`).

That last step is where your problem lies. The browser doesn't force the elements to first be 0 pixels wide and all grow evenly. The browser simply starts with the smallest flex-child, giving it more width until it has grown as wide as the **second** smallest. At that point both of these flex-children will both grow evenly. And so forth, adding width until all space is distributed. This is also why `box-sizing: border-box` seems to not working.

You can fix this by adding a container to each of the flex-items, which has the border-box part applied. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/0vufq79d/). The contents have been wrapped into another div, and the styles have been applied to it as well (except for the flex-specific properties, of course).