How do I achieve this layout for a Form Stepper in CSS, where the dashes are able to be part of 2 different flexboxes?
Building a form stepper component, where the step titles can be different lengths, however the step  buttons themselves should be constant length. A bit like this one from Material UI: 
I had tried using relative and absolute postitioning and negative margins to try to get the dash in between the steps a constant distance from the circles, but to no avail. Not sure how to achieve this with flexboxes, since they dont seem to like to mesh together. Furthermore I am rendering the steps in a loop (v-for). My initial idea was to render the dash, position it to the right place, adn render the next component, but the dash causes the next component to render with a further space. Barebones sample of my code, as my current implementation is quite far from my initial idea.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="form-stepper">
    
        <div class="step-component">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="text">Step1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash"></div>
        
        <div class="step-component">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="text">Step2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash"></div>
        
        <div class="step-component">
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="text">Step3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash"></div>
    
    </div>

</body>

<style>
    .form-stepper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: rows;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .step-component {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }   
    
    .button {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
}
    
    .dash {
        width: 60px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #bbb;
    }
</style>
</html>



I recommend finding a CSS tutorial for such a thing, and then using the v-for to make it more custom and self-adapting.

You can put each dash inside of its step-component, so it can anchor off of the step-component's positioning. Also since you have 3 components you only need 2 dashes; the first step-component does not need one.
Position the dashes using absolute positioning so that they can be offset to the left of their parent (the step-component).


.form-stepper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* FYI 'row' is the correct value; not 'rows' */
}

.step-component {
  flex: 1; /* Makes each step have equal width: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066844/4904996 */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative; /* So the absolute position dash marks can anchor to this */
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px; /* Chosen because it's about half the button height */
  left: calc(-50% + 20px); /* the +20px provides a little padding between the button and the dash */
  right: calc(50% + 20px);
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-stepper">

    <div class="step-component">
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="text">Step1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="step-component">
      <div class="dash"></div>
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="text">Step2 with an extra long name to test wrapping</div>
    </div>

    <div class="step-component">
      <div class="dash"></div>
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="text">Step3</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>



